# How can I write UTF-8 character to XML file in NetBean 6.9.1

Tags: java

I use Dom4J to write a XML file. Although I have added `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to `netbeans.config`, I couldn't see the XML file because it had UTF-8 characters. Could you suggest anything?

Answer (score 1):

Check here http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/How-to-save-html-pages-as-UTF-8-and-open-it-correctly-td2920145.html
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqI18nProjectEncoding